# Visual Studio 2017 - Angular - Webpack - SASS - style not applied

Tags: angular, visual-studio, webpack, sass

I created a new angular app from visual studio. It didn't have support for `sass`.

I installed `node-sass`, `raw-loader` and `sas-loader` and added that line into webpack.config.js:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["raw-loader", "sass-loader"] }
```

I added this into my home component:

```
styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
```

the `home.component.scss` file only contains the following:

```
.body {
    background-color: red
}
```

The website runs with no error but background is white. Also, I don't see and corresponding css file (where should it be?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the empty visual studio template, '.body' does not match any elements in the home component.

to test, try 'home.component.scss':

```
$primary-color: red;
h1 {
    color: $primary-color;
}
```

There is no corresponding css file, compiled css is written to a style tag in html:

```
<style>
h1[_ngcontent-c2] {
  color: red; }
</style>
```